# program to find the sum of deepest leaves of a tree using C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

I saw this question on leetcode, which is to find sum of deepest nodes of a tree. The code I submitted gives the correct answer while testing, but gives wrong input while submission for the same test case.
The link to question: https://leetcode.com/problems/deepest-leaves-sum/

My code:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
map<int,int> m;
class Solution {
public:
void level(TreeNode* root,int n)
    {
        if(root!=NULL)
        {
        m[n]+=root->val;
        level(root->left,n+1);
        level(root->right,n+1);
    }
  //  return m;
    }
    int deepestLeavesSum(TreeNode* root) {

        level(root,1);

        return m.rbegin()->second;
    }
};
```

the problematic test case: [6,7,8,2,7,1,3,9,null,1,4,null,null,null,5]

Comment: the answer to the corresponding test case is supposed to be 19 and my code while testing gives 19.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] example with input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to guess it might be running multiple test cases using your Solution class. You're storing your results  in a variable outside of the solution class so it might not be getting reinitialized between runs.

Edit: To be specific it looks like this might be the problem:.

std::map m; // seems to be in file scope